# Syntax of arrays of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am new to c++ programming and trying to understand this syntax

```
int **arr;

arr = new int *[5];
```

I am confused about this part `new int *[5]`; Does it mean pointer of type int to 5 subpointers?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Does it mean pointer of type int to 5 subpointers?` More like a pointer of type "int pointer", and a 5 element array with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will hopefully become clear when you read it piece by piece:

```
new        int *             [5]
^^^        ^^^^^             ^^^
give me    pointers to int   and five of those.
```

Then you safe the address of the first of the new pointers in `arr` and thus have an dynamically allocated array of five pointers.

Note that "in the real world" (i.e. if no teacher/prof forbids you to) you would use an `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring an array of pointers to integers.
The array capacity is 5 (pointers).
The variable is allocated in *dynamic* memory because of `new`.

Answer (score 1):

When you have problem with a non trivial type use typedef (at least in your head):

```
typedef int* int_ptr;
int_ptr *arr;
arr = new int_ptr[5];
```

It is easier to understand now, is it not?